# Программа уходит в бесконечный цикл, хотя не должна

Tags: c++, winapi, циклы

Есть вот такой код на с++:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void m_click(short int times)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(25);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

void main()
{
    for (;; Sleep(25))
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
            m_click(2);
}
```

Как вы понимаете программа должна считывать физическое нажатие на кнопку мыши(именно физическое) и после этого посылать 2 нажатия, но программа входит в бесконечный цикл и начинает бесконечно кликать, предположительно из-за того, что она считывает те же нажатия, что и посылает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

P. s. я имею ввиду не основной цикл `for()` в функции `main()`, а тот который вызывается из-за функции `m_click()`, и условия `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))`

Comment: а программа как-то должна прекращаться? где это в коде?

Comment: Так а что вы хотите? программа честно перехватывает нажатия. Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @Zhihar, я имею ввиду не основной цикл for() в функции main(), а тот который вызывается из-за функции m_click().

Comment: @Zhihar,  я понимаю, но из за этого происходит второй бесконечный цикл, вследствие которого программа начинает кликать без остановки.

Answer (score 2):

Да сделайте простейший вывод

```
void m_click(short int times)
{
    cout << "Start" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(25);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    cout << "Stop" << endl;
}
```

и убедитесь, что цикл не бесконечен! просто ваш цикл в `main` перехватывает эти ваши нажатия из цикла...

Если вы поясните, как вы бы хотели, чтоб вела себя программа - можно будет обсуждать пути решения. Сейчас же только можно говорить, что все отрабатывает корректно...

Comment: Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы по одному нажатию, программа посылала 2 нажатия и не больше. Но при этом нажатия из m_click(), не должны считываться функцией main().

Comment: А кем они должны считываться? Кто их заберет из буфера?

Comment: Извините, не понял(

Comment: Вы создали 2 нажатия ЛКМ. Они ушли в системный буфер событий. Переданы в программу. Программа на них реагирует, вызывая... - вы создаете бесконечную рекурсию. Каково условие выхода из рекурсии? Вы можете просто прекратить выполнение цикла, или перестать вызывать функцию нажатия - но вы должны как-то освободить буфер от событий нажатия мыши.

Comment: Так мне как раз таки нужно избежать этой бесконечной рекурсии, связанной с бесконечными нажатиями, но при этом благодаря циклу for() в main(), программа должна работать бесконечно, пока я ее не закрою.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы когда я кликнул 1 раз программа послала 2 нажатия и ожидала  моего следующего нажатия, именно моего, а не того которая послала сама.

Comment: Опять 25 pf рыбу гроши... **КУДА** послала? Она и посылает - СЕБЕ. Не хотите, чтоб посылала - не вызывайте `m_click`. Пока эти нажатия не обработаны, они будут болтаться в буфере...

Comment: А как тогда решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Точно сформулировать задачу... Одно решение я подсказал - раз вы не хотите, чтобы эти нажатия читались - так и не пишите их. Пустая функция `m_click()` - вполне себе решение...

Comment: Извините пожалуйста за неточность моих формулировок и за потраченное мною время, но ваш комментарий про буфер событий натолкнул меня на мысль о том,  чтобы ставить некий фильтр на эти нажатия. Я добавил ответ на свой вопрос.